# Call to undefined method after upgrading to laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have tried to upgrade my project to laravel 5.4 from 5.3 today. I added

```
"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
```

To my `composer.json` and run the command `composer update` and then `composer dump-autoload` and then tested my project. It gives me this error:

Error:

> FatalThrowableError in 2154f392745gf102547be138a945a11b58e5649203.php
>   line 2:
>       Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Factory::getFirstLoop()

Did I miss something?

Comment: The location of getFirstLoop has been updated to Concerns/ManagesLoops with different name 

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/View/Concerns/ManagesLoops.php#L74 

It tells that it gets the last item but has same return value as

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php#L852

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Clear your compiled blade views.

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 10):

1. `php artisan cache:clear`

   > Flush the application cache
2. `composer dump-autoload`

   > Generate autoload files
3. `php artisan view:clear`

   > Clear all compiled view files

Comment: Curious, I tried both of these methods and still seeing the same error.   I have the same code pulled down on a dev server where it works and then on my production server, where it's failing, which is odd.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading packages and Laravel to 5.4 , you should run **

> php artisan view:clear

** to avoid the mentioned error.
further more you may run **

> php artisan route:clear

** to flush the route cache.
Additionally , you may run

> **php artisan optimize**

at last.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files from this path

```
{project_root}\storage\framework\views
```

Or
Run this in console

```
php artisan view:clear
```